# Azure Data Factory - Add current time & random numbers

Tags: datetime, azure-data-factory, pipeline

In Azure Data Factory, I am preparing a pipeline for some data that I could like to run. I have a dynamic content script for the output of a Copy Data activity (attached are visualised data factory and output file).

**QUESTION**: When I add the timezone script, why does the output file in the blob storage show random numbers at the end of the file (i.e. the "7539827")? What can I do to remove this?

Following are the scripts for the original dynamic content and the script with the date.

Original Dynamic Content script

```
@concat('     _',pipeline().parameters.SliceStart,"_')
```

Script with Timezone

```
@concat('Test_',convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),'_')
```

Images:
[visualised data factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBzdl.png) ,
[csv output in blob storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9szbF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try mentioning the format like this

@concat('Test_',formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcnow(),'UTC','New Zealand Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss'), '.csv')